# Не скачиваются файл по https ссылке через wget

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssl, wget

При попытке скачать файл по https ссылке через wget процесс просто зависает на подключении, ошибок не выдает, висит до таймаута.

Файл маленький 170 Кб, через браузер скачивается нормально, той же самой командой на другом хостинге скачивается нормально.

По http на этом сервере файлы скачиваются нормально, проблема только с https.

--no-check-certificate не помогает.

Вот пример результата:

```
--2018-12-08 20:52:42-- https://example.org/api/118505.tar.bz2?token=123456 

Resolving example.org (example.org)... 192.0.2.0 

Connecting to example.org (example.org)|192.0.2.0|:443... failed: Connection timed out. 

Retrying.
```

Comment: проблема только с одним сервером или со всеми? есть ли какие-то прокси в системе/в браузере в котором проверяешь? ЗЫ: ip-адрес `123.456.789.123` не корректен, а для примеров специально выделены 3 диапазона: `192.0.2.0/24` `198.51.100.0/24` `203.0.113.0/24`

Comment: У меня один сервер и один хостинг, на хостинге работает нормально, на сервере не работает. Прокси нет. За ip спасибо, поправил.

Comment: я имел в виду с сервера к любому узлу https доступ виснет или только к конкретному? а в `iptables` какого-нибудь странного правила не завалялось ли?

Comment: Разобрался с проблемой, в итоге выяснилось что подсеть ip, из который мне выделили ip адрес, по неизвестной причине забанена хостингом сервиса, с которого я получаю файлы. Помогла трассировка по ip адресу сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с проблемой, в итоге выяснилось что подсеть ip, из который мне выделили ip адрес, по неизвестной причине забанена хостингом сервиса, с которого я получаю файлы. Помогла трассировка по ip адресу сайта.